# Using R sorting and grouping table

Tags: r, csv

I have this big data table with have more details but i'm just showing some example

```
 data

                 Source   | Protocol
                  10.0.0.6  SSDP    
                  10.0.0.6  TCP
                  10.0.0.6  HTTP
                  10.0.0.6  BROWSER
                  10.0.0.6  LLMNR
                  10.0.0.6  NBNS
                  10.0.0.10 MDNS
                  10.0.0.10 ICMPv6 
                  10.0.0.10 IGMPv3
                  10.0.0.10 HTTP/XML
```

So i have created a table called port.

```
Protocol
SSDP
ARP
TCP
HTTP
BROWSER
LLMNR
NBNS
DHCPv6
MDNS
ICMPv6
IGMPv3
HTTP/XML
```

Is there a way to make the table port look like this without hard coding it. Is it by using loop?
PS , :( forgive me, I'm just learning R.

The port table will create a new column by itself determine on how many source ip it contains in the data and implement 0/1 if the ip is using the port.

```
Protocol 10.0.0.6 10.0.0.10
SSDP        1         0
ARP         0         0
TCP         1         0
HTTP        1         0
BROWSER     1         0
LLMNR       1         0
NBNS        1         0
DHCPv6      0         0
MDNS        0         1
ICMPv6      0         1
IGMPv3      0         1
HTTP/XML    0         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the simplest level, it sounds like you would want `table`:

```
with(mydf, table(Protocol, Source))
```

Since `table` tabulates (and thus, might give values greater than one if more than one value matches that combination) you might need to do some further processing. Also, since your original dataset doesn't seem to have all the `factor` levels, you would also need to use `factor`:

```
port <- c("SSDP", "ARP", "TCP", "HTTP", "BROWSER", "LLMNR", 
          "NBNS", "DHCPv6", "MDNS", "ICMPv6", "IGMPv3", "HTTP/XML")

(with(mydf, table(factor(Protocol, port), Source)) > 0) * 1
#           Source
#            10.0.0.10 10.0.0.6
#   SSDP             0        1
#   ARP              0        0
#   TCP              0        1
#   HTTP             0        1
#   BROWSER          0        1
#   LLMNR            0        1
#   NBNS             0        1
#   DHCPv6           0        0
#   MDNS             1        0
#   ICMPv6           1        0
#   IGMPv3           1        0
#   HTTP/XML         1        0
```

---

### Update

Some further examples to demonstrate:

1. Why I used `> 0) * 1`
2. What effect `droplevels` would have when removing certain values

```
## Imagine this is the source data.frame
## We don't want "A" values from "Source"
## We do want all relevant levels in "Protocol"
##   which, for this example, we can assume to
##   be 1, 2, and 3
mydf <- data.frame(Source = c("A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "C"),
                   Protocol = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1))

## Now, compare the following

with(mydf, table(factor(Protocol, 1:3), Source))

with(mydf[!mydf$Source %in% "A", ], 
     table(factor(Protocol, 1:3), Source))

with(droplevels(mydf[!mydf$Source %in% "A", ]), 
     table(factor(Protocol, 1:3), Source))
```

Comment: Or `t(table(mydf))` for the same result +1

Comment: Okay, fine.  Not any more

Comment: @RichardScriven, I've sometimes wondered (but never tested) whether `t(table(mydf))` would be faster than `table(rev(mydf))`. Hmm...

Comment: Probably not much difference in speed, I bet

Comment: oh thanks its working :) ! um but now can i filter away the source that i doesnt want which is like eg, fe80::16e:8d02:e94e:396f

Comment: have already use data <- subset (data[grep("^\\d+\\.\\d+.\\d+\\.",data$Source),])  to filter out at the beginning

Comment: @sy1993, drop those values from your `data.frame` before using `table` (and if the values in the "source" column are `factors`, you might also need to use `droplevels` to remove them from the output of `table`).

Comment: `rev.default` uses the single line `if (length(x)) x[length(x):1L] else x`, whereas `t.default`, dispatches from `t.data.frame` and uses a `.Internal`

Comment: @AnandaMahto,RichardScriven, Thanks i appreciate you guys helping! But i dont quite understand >.<

Comment: @sy1993, I've added an update to show what I was referring to with `droplevels` and so on. Richard and I were just having a discussion on what the best approaches might be.

Comment: @AnandaMahto and RichardScriven thanks to you both  i've understand the droplevels, but the problem is there are alot of different source that i want to filter out in a big datafile, so does this work? with(droplevels(data[grep("^\\d+\\.\\d+.\\d+\\.",data$Source),]) sorry if i've been irritaing

Comment: @sy1993, looks like it should (but I don't see your `table` step in there).

Comment: @AnandaMahto it gives this error, Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : argument is missing, with no default